# Autoplay embed videos in html 5

Tags: html, loops, video-streaming, embed, autoplay

I am trying to make a really basic deviation information overview for my big screen tv at work.

My problem is that i want the video to start by itself when the computer starts, I have already set up so that chrome and everything else starts when the pc boots. So if anyone have an easy answer to this it will be much appreciated!

My dream is to have a local html 5 webpage for the computer with multiple videos and twitter feeds so that i have full overview about the traffic and such, without having to CLICK start and refreshing the page when it stops.

I have copied an embed shortcut below:

```
<div style="position:relative; width:100%; height:0; padding-bottom:56.25%; overflow:hidden;"><iframe style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; top:0; left:0;" src="//mm.aftenposten.no/video/embed/?vendor=bt&id=100573" frameborder="0"  allowfullscreen="true" /></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable autoplay, you can use the `video` tag instead of an `iframe`:

```
<div style="position:relative; width:100%; height:0; padding-bottom:56.25%; overflow:hidden;">
  <video autoplay>
    <source>src="mm.aftenposten.no/video/embed/?vendor=bt&id=100573" type="video/mp4"</source>
  </video>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could use JavaScript to select the `iframe` element and click on it, which would start the video.